# Jquery async/await ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I'm currently using 3 ajax call methods (3 of them are executing back-to-back). I must have a time delay in between the second ajax call and the third one. If I add "async:false" in the second ajax, everything works like a charm. However, I found out that this is really a terrible practice and shouldn't be using. 
So I decided to try an async/await. This is my first time, so have no luck. I would be really grateful if you guys could add some explanations so I can learn. Thank you so much.

```
//This is the second ajax method that I've been trying to use async/await
async function InsertAssignments(data) {
    var insertNewData = api + "/Point/insert_data/";
    await $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: insertNewData + data,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        timeout: 30000,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#mainGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            $("#ListBox1").data("kendoListBox").dataSource.read();
            $("#ListBox2").data("kendoListBox").dataSource.read();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $('#gridMessage').html(xhr.responseText).css("color", "red");
        }
    });
}
```

and then I'm calling InsertAssignments(data) somewhere.

Comment: That looks like one request. Where are the other two?

Comment: Can you respond? It's unclear which 3 requests you're referring to

Comment: The other two are working just fine. I do not need add async:false in them. I only just want async/await in this ajax method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. `Async` / `await` requires functions to return a promise.
2. jQuery `$.ajax()` can be used in two ways: with callbacks and promises. Your code is using a callback, not a promise.

Wrap `$.ajax()` in a function like this:

```
async function doAjax(url, params = {}, method = 'POST') {
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: method,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: params
    });
}
```

Then use `await doAjax()` whenever you are making an ajax call.

```
async function InsertAssignments(data) {
  const insertNewData = api + '/Point/insert_data/';
  try {
    // You can make multiple ajax calls
    // Response data is stored in result
    const result = await doAjax(insertNewData, data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error! InsertAssignments:', error);
    $('#gridMessage').html(error.message).css('color', 'red');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this is pretty close to what I really want. I'm trying to use this, but still I don't think I understood well enough. 

Now I know async/await requires two parts. Can you please check these?
So the promise part, this is what I have.

`async function WaitAssignmentAjax(url, params) {
const insertNewData = api + "\Point/insert_data/";
   try {
      return await $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : insertNewData + params,
         dataType: "json",
         data: params
         });
     }
    catch (error) {
    alert(error);
     }`

Comment: `async function InsertAssignments (data) {
    const insertAssignments = const insertNewData = api + "/Point/insert_data/";
    try {
       const result = await WaitAssignmentAjax(insertNewData, params);
     }
   catch (error) {
    $('#gridMessage').html(error.message).css("color", "red");
    });`

Comment: Sorry it looks really messy here. But if I use  do `await WaitAssignments();` somewhere in my code that I want this to be executed, it says await has to be in async function. 

Where can I call     await WaitAssignments(); ? in the async function InsertAssignments(data)? 

I'm sorry this is my first time using it so I'm confused

Comment: Sorry for the previous silly questions. I finally got it working! I just changed all 3 ajax calls to async/await functions and they are working great! Feels so good that I learned something cool haha. I could have just put async:false as an easy/quick fix, but I wanted to handle it properly. Thank you so much for your help though.

Comment: Please note that `return await` is redundant since the function with `async` keyword returns a Promise regardless and any calling code will have to `await` the resulting Promise (unless you *really* need to handle the rejection inside the `doAjax` [i.e. one or more of the calls failing is expected] - which, given the calling code is already wrapped in `try...catch` seems to not be necessary).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine what is redundant

Comment: @PawanDeore `return await` that is no longer present in the post (the OP edited it out after we discussed why it is so) in an `async` function, see discussion above. `await`ing an `async` function call unwraps `return`ed promises, so there is no need to use `return await`, hence it is redundant.