# Ajax request stop all the website during the working time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an issue about a big ajax request: I make a query on a php files which make some curl request, it takes 15-20 seconds to complete, then return some json on my webpage. It's a classic ajax request, but I discovered a strange bug,

When the ajax query is running (type GET), I can't use my website in Chrome, all the pages stay blank until the ajax request is completed,

So I thought the ajax request broken my server, but the site perfectly works on other devices (mobile, other chrome session, ...). It's only the current chrome session which become laggy and work only when the ajax request is completed.

Could you please explain me why?
My ajax request is basic:

```
                    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            action: "loadPageContent"
        },
        success: function(retour) {
            localStorage.removeItem('myhtml');
            if(retour.status && retour.htmlDatas){
                storedDatas["posts"] = retour.htmlDatas;                        
                storedDatas["date_scrapping"] = retour.date_scrapping;                      
                localStorage.setItem("myhtml", JSON.stringify(storedDatas) ); // ¨Pour si relance

                $('#container').html(retour.htmlDatas);
                

            }
            else {
                alert('error');
            }

        },
        error: function(retour) {
            alert('error');
        },  
    });
```

Comment: You can use async request for don't stop your browser. If you want to use jquery you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349890/jquery-async-await-ajax-call where you can find the code for make async ajax request.

Comment: If you have called `session_start()` in your PHP code you cannot call it again [eg: process a second request] until either that request completes, or you call [`sesssion_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close). If you are about to do something long-running, you don't need `$_SESSION` anymore, and want to free up the lock, call `session_write_close()` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

use promise and handle the response:

```
async function runCodes(){

    //this code its gonna run async
    ajaxCall().then((response)=>{
       if(response){
          //true
       } else {
          //false
       }
    });

    //some other codes

}
    
    function ajaxCall(){
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/controller.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                action: "loadPageContent"
            },
            success: function(retour) {
                localStorage.removeItem('myhtml');
                if(retour.status && retour.htmlDatas){
                    storedDatas["posts"] = retour.htmlDatas;                        
                    storedDatas["date_scrapping"] = retour.date_scrapping;                      
                    localStorage.setItem("myhtml", JSON.stringify(storedDatas) ); // ¨Pour si relance
    
                    $('#container').html(retour.htmlDatas);
                    resolve(true);
    
                }
                else {
                    alert('error');
                    resolve(false);
                }
    
            },
            error: function(retour) {
                alert('error');
                resolve(false);
            },  
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it didn't fix the bug, my site is still down on chrome during the ajax request, and all my others ajax request are pending until this one is completed

Comment: After testing to open my url thought the browser, I have the same lag effect, I can't change or refresh pages on another tab while the script is running, I think it's cause of the curl request, but I have a very good server, so it's not a crash or lag, i don't know why

Comment: Becouse you need to paste all in an async function to work! I change the answer code!